# why permissions section for Database user is empty in MS Sql server 2008R2

Tags: user-interface, sql-server-2008-r2, user-permissions

**NOTE: I am note DB Admin and I am not that much in sql server security**

I am using MS SQL SERVER 2008R2

What I want to do is to give a user a minimal permissions or just what he required

I have a local user in my windows and I add this user in the logins of the database after that I went to this user in my specific database and try to change his set of permissions but the section is coming empty

[image: securables sqlserver user]

why it is coming empty?

and how to do this, I mean giving him the permissions that he just need nothing more?

**Please I want to do this from the user interface without T-sql**

**EDIT**

I Just want to give the user read, write, execute nothing more

and also I need to know more about how to control users permissions in more details

Comment: You haven't indicate what permissions he requires, but for example if you go back to the Login area and select the Server Login, then select the database, note that down the bottom you can select database roles such as `db_datareader`. Are you trying to set permissions for specific tables / fields? You would not do this at the user level.

Comment: I have edited my question for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A. Set up Read/Write

1. Go to Security/Logins and find your login, double click it
2. Go to user mapping, and click on the database that you have access to
3. In the bottom pane under 'Database Role Membership', tick `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter`

This gives the user Login SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE

B. Revoke DELETE and grant EXECUTE

Create a role that does this:

1. Go to your database / Security / Roles
2. Right click, New / Database Role
3. Give the role a name, I will use `executor` for this example and press OK

I don't know how to do the next steps in SSMS, You'll need to do it in T-SQL:

1. Start a new query in your database
2. Type this and press F5:

   `GRANT EXECUTE TO executor;`

   `DENY DELETE TO executor;`

Now repeat A3 but select your newly created role, 'executor'

Every new user (or group) that you create needs to be a member of these three roles. The best practice is to add a windows group to SQL Server once, and add users to that windows group.

Lastly test this - I don't know for sure that it works.

With regards to the database user securables:

You have to explicitly populate this list to see what it contains. It doesn't populate automatically. Press Search and search for some objects (i.e. all objects belonging to the schema dbo). Now you have a list of objects in the top. Click on an object and click the 'Effecttive' tab on the bottom. This is the users effective (final) permissions for this object. If you want to override this at the object level you can assign something on the explicit tab

Comment: Ok now I can control the permissions for the user but you didn't answer my main question why its not showing any permissions as in the PIC, thanks

Comment: You have to explicitly populate this list to see what it contains. It doesn't populate automatically. Press Search and search for some objects (i.e. all objects belonging to the schema dbo). Now you have a list of objects in the top. Click on an object and click the 'Effecttive' tab on the bottom. This is the users effective (final) permissions for this object. If you want to override this at the object level you can assign something on the  explicit tab.

Comment: I have found what you have pointed me to, actually that's weird because I used to have this list automatically whatever now can you please add your comment to the answer so it would be complete answer and I can restfully mark your answer as valid one, thanks

Comment: I hope you found this helpful :)

Comment: I added another question if you are intersted
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574393/control-users-permissions-in-sqlserver-according-to-asp-net-forms-users-roles

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem after our MSSQL Server was restored on a new server and wanted to set explicit permissions for a user in a DB.

Not sure how to make it default (as it appears to have been previously), but basically just hit the search button in the `Securables` tab you show to search for *"All objects of the types..."* and choose the `Databases` object and click ok / search. You should now see securables for that specific database and can set explicit permissions as well as view existing "effective" permissions.
[image]
[image]